# Migrating application from Spring to CDI

Tags: spring, cdi

I would like to migrate an application from Spring 3 to Weld. In order not to rewrite the whole bean configuration at once, it would be cool if I could inject part of the application that is still written in Spring in the new CDI part.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible. CDI has an extension system where you can hook into the injection mechanism. From there you can manually bootstrap your Spring beans and then return those.

I wouldn't be surprised if there's already an extension for this, so before looking into writing one yourself check if there's not one already.

Answer (score 0):

There have been a few attempts at making CDI and Spring work together.  Take a look at CDI Advocate for one.

It comes down to how much of your app is spring.  If you're running something like Spring MVC, it'll be very difficult since it manages essentially your whole app.

Comment: So much for the old mantra that Spring is completely non-invasive to an application and that you can remove Spring without your app noticing it :X